# Why would a query block if no locks are taken out?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I ran a query all day yesterday. Takes about 2 hours per run. There were no issues. I was monitoring the locks taken out and checking for blocked processes. There is a process that has to run every 15 minutes so I account for that by checking the contents of a table and then waiting until it's  empty (the process will empty it when it's done). Then my query proceeds.

I turn this query on again as I'm leaving for the day and I come in this morning to see emails that the process started blocking just 5 minutes after I left.

The sp_who2 shows that my process was currently in the 'WAITFOR' command and my query output shows the same thing. No locks were out at that time. But it was blocking other processes still.

Why would the process block if no locks were taken out and why would it block when NO inserts are being performed? The WAITFOR is at the top of a while loop. Again, I ran this all day with no issues. It waited for the process to finish like it should and then continued on.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
go

declare @start bigint
declare @end bigint
declare @max bigint
declare @step int

set @step = 49999
set @start = 120790808
set @end = @start + @step
set @max = @start + 50000000

while ( @end < @max )
begin

while (select COUNT(*) from SomeOtherTable (nolock)) > 0
begin
    print 'Waiting for process'
    waitfor delay '00:00:30'
end

begin transaction

update [TableA] with (tablock)
set [TableA].[ColumnA] = [TableB].[ColumnA]
from [TableB] (nolock)
where [TableB].[ColumnB] = [TableA].[ColumnB]
and [TableA].ID >= @start 
and [TableA].ID <  @end

commit transaction

print @end

if @end >= @max 
begin
    break
end

set @start = @end
set @end = @end + @step

end
```

Comment: What was it blocking?  It's possible there was a very high isolation level on the other process.

Comment: NoLock is not entirely lock free, it still issues a Sch-S lock, was anything trying to modify the table schema during that window?

Comment: Thats the thing, it was blocking a process that had ran all throughout the day while I was monitoring and there were no issues. However, there was a job step it was also blocking. I'm waiting for the other dev to get in so I can figure out what it does.

Comment: @Andrew, no, nothing I was selecting from was modified. TableB is not in use by anything. TableA is though, but with the chunking using a tablock it was pretty fast and wasn't causing any blocks... at least any that were blocked for a long time.

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels `TABLOCK` by definition blocks other processes on that table...

Comment: @JNK I know, but I use it because it's much faster than what I was doing before. It only takes about 2-3 minutes for each iteration of the while loop and was not causing any issues for the previous 8 hours. But the sp_who2 shows the process was sitting at 'WAITFOR' not the 'INSERT'.

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels is it possible the proc was started then stopped?  I ask because if you have a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` without a rollback or commit, that can lock a table as well.

Comment: @JNK Ahhh, that makes sense. I stopped it before I left to update the numbers, then started it again. But it shows that it ran through several iterations of the loop and then it shows it waited 1600 times before it was killed. Can the process take out multiple locks without releasing previous locks?

Comment: @JNK would the transaction log being full have anything to do with it?

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels - yes to the multiple locks.  Trans log would just cause it to generate an error I think.

Comment: @JNK I think you're right about the transaction holding the lock. It makes most sense given the time line and other evidence. Please put it as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a query like the one posted that includes explicit transactions but no error trapping, it's possible (likely) to have a transaction left open.

If the `BEGIN TRAN` executes but you never `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` the transaction will be held open indefinitely, which can cause all sorts of hard-to-trace blocking issues.

Comment: I believe when I stopped execution, it did not do the commit and held the transaction open which held the tablock. It makes most sense considering the timeline and evidence.

Answer (score 0):

yes, like @ILovePaperTowels said - `update [TableA] with (tablock)` means a table level lock. it overrides your isolation level

Comment: sp_who2 shows the process was sitting at 'WAITFOR' not the 'INSERT'.

Comment: Waitfor process has a non-zero value in the "blocked" column. look for that spid. I would be surprised if it isn't your update statement.